# Java sockets and dataoutputstream delay

Tags: java, sockets, dataoutputstream

I am a beginner in Java and I am working at a project involving sockets and external devices.
I have done a small listener for the units and I am having some problems sending messages to the devices.

The unit has 2 messages that is sending to the server:
1. the Heart Beat message witch is in hex
2. the actual data which is a string and looks like: field1,field2,field3,field4

The listener is opening a new thread for each device and is wait for messages.
I use an DataInputStream for receiving the messages and DataOutputStream for sending the messages. Each time a unit is connecting to the server, it opens a new thread and gets the heart beat, from that heart beat I know what type of device is and who is it. If the device is new I will configure it based on 2 unique serials which the unit knows to send me and I have to compare them to the database.

My problem is in the part in which I ask the device for the 2 serials. It takes a long time 30 to 40 seconds. It has to be under 10 seconds for send the command (tested on another tcp server).

Here is that part of code:

```
String [] commands = deviceDetails.getConfigCommands().split(";"); // I take the commands from a file, and looks like: command1;command2
for (int i=0; i<commands.length; i++) {
sendCommand = commands[i].getBytes(); // sendCommand is a byte[]
out.write(sendCommand);
out.flush();

loop: while (true) {
    in.read(buffer); // buffer is a byte[]
    String[] result = new String(buffer, "ASCII").split(":|="); // the response from the unit looks like: ok:commandname=code, i need the code

    if (configCounter ==2 && imei.equals("")) {
        i = 0;
        break loop;
    } else if(configCounter == 2 && simid.equals("")) {
        i = 1;
        break loop;
    }
    configCounter++;

    switch (result[1]) {
        case "IMEI":
            imei = result[2];
            break loop;

        case "SIMID":
            simid = result[2];
            break loop;
    }
}
```

}

in the while I am waiting for the response from the unit. but before that I am trying to send the command to the unit and it takes about 30-40 second for each command.

Can anyone tell me what's the problem in the code above? How can I make the DataOutputStream send the command faster than 30-40 seconds??

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect your receiver is expecting a line of text e.g. a new line or something else different and is timing out.  An unbuffered DataOutputStream should take less than 10 micro-seconds to write.

Comment: Well I have tried to send the command and a new line but the result is the same. Thank you for the interest and the idea.

Comment: You are ignoring the count returned by `read()`. If it is -1 the peer has closed the connection, and you must close this socket and exit the loop. If it is less than the message length you are expecting, you need to loop around the `read()` call, gathering more of the message until it is complete, whatever that means in your protocol.

Comment: Yes it is true, but even if I delete the while and try to send only one commad, I have the same delay. Thank you!

Comment: I solve the mystery, I had to add after each command a carriage return. Thank you Peter Lawrey for guidance and tips. Thank you all for your reply.